# ORACLE: Select row, if most recent value of column equals X

Tags: oracle, select, max

I'll preemptively say I search the other questions and online, however could not find it.  Whether that be poor wording choice on my part, or otherwise.

I have a ticketing queue and searching through it's history.  Column "Group" will contain the group name that owns the ticket upon a transfer action.  There are many other actions, such as just adding comments to the ticket.  I am only interested if the most recent value in the column (ignoring nulls) if it is "QUEUE_X".

I know this is improper because of the group-function but this is logically how I view it:

```
select
    * 
from 
    ticket_history
where
    max(group) = 'QUEUE_X'
order by
    date
;
```

I don't want to strictly do `where group = 'X'` because tickets can be transferred around a lot and I only care about the tickets in my queue at the current time.  Also, I cannot find if or where the original developer put a CURRENT_QUEUE-like column, so out of luck the easy way.  Don't take it too literal, just wanted to illustrate the null values in GROUP and I'd like the most recent value to equal Queue_X

Example table data of a ticket I would **NOT** want (though if the query occured at 12:12, I would have):

```
STRT_DATE     | PERSON | GROUP   | TICKET_NUM | END_DATE
12/3/15 12:00 | Ted    | Queue_Y | 111111     | 12/3/15 12:05
12/3/15 12:05 | Bob    |         | 111111     | 12/3/15 12:10
12/3/15 12:10 | Ted    | Queue_Y | 222222     | 12/3/15 12:45
12/3/15 12:10 | Bob    | Queue_X | 111111     | 12/3/15 12:15
12/3/15 12:15 | Bob    |         | 222222     | 12/3/15 12:45
12/3/15 12:15 | Mary   | Queue_Y | 111111     | 12/3/15 12:25
12/3/15 12:25 | Ted    |         | 222222     | 12/3/15 12:35
12/3/15 12:35 | Ted    |         | 333333     | 12/3/15 12:45
12/3/15 12:35 | Bob    | Queue_X | 333333     | 12/3/15 12:45
12/3/15 12:45 | Ted    |         | 111111     | 12/3/15 12:55
12/3/15 12:55 | Bob    | Queue_X | 111111     | 12/3/15 12:56
```

Desired Results:

```
12/3/15 12:35 | Bob    | Queue_X | 333333     | 12/3/15 12:45
12/3/15 12:55 | Bob    | Queue_X | 111111     | 12/3/15 12:56
```

(Still in Queue_Y):

```
12/3/15 12:10 | Ted    | Queue_Y | 222222     | 12/3/15 12:45
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Added more tickets and an additional member to Queue_Y (so there is not a 1-1 relationship between queue and person)

Comment: Either I did not see or you fail to mention what column you want the max, it can not be the group for sure! Is it STRT_DATE ?

Comment: I had it there though obviously in error, GROUP.  I'm probably thinking about it backwards and misinterpreting max.  Essentially, I would like the row only if the GROUP is equal to Queue_X for the most recent row .

Comment: Please, just for comparison add more rows with the same Queue_X and from that data show what would be your desired result.

Comment: @Jorge Just added additional tickets and one more member to Queue_Y

Comment: How do you define `max(group)` ? Why Queue_X is a "max", while `Queue_Y` is greater that `Queue_X` (when they are compared as strings) ?  In some comment you wrote "I'm only interested in the lastest rows" - how do you define "latest row" ? Should only last 10/1000/100000 rows be considered by the query ? Or maybe `latest` means rows from last 10 seconds, last 10 hours or last 10 years (if yes then which date shoulb be considered - STRT_DATE or END_DATE )?

Comment: @kordirko I think my guess at understanding max in relation of characters was skewed, but latest as in most recent change (using STRT_DATE) based upon a TICKET_NUM where GROUP is not NULL.  Essentially using those values, I am only interested in values where GROUP = Queue_X.  As I write it out this way, I feel like I should be able to do this- if I weren't so exhausted.  The max() function was interpretted as most_recent_non_null().

Answer (score 0):

Try this (edited):

```
select strt_date, person, group, ticket_num, end_date
from ticket_history
where (rowid, end_date) IN (select rowid, max(end_date)
                           from ticket_history
                           where group = 'QUEUE_X'
                           group by rowid)
order by end_date;
```

This will reflect what you show in your desired output.

Comment: It appears this is getting all occurences of transfers, including those from the past, instead of only the ones in the current queue of 'QUEUE_X'.

Comment: Do you want only transfers from QUEUE_X? And if so, do you want only the latest transfer?

Comment: Exactly.  I added two additional tickets to the example data and example desired output too to help illustrate.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try the edited version above -- it shows your desired results.  If you want the end_date in reverse order, that's a slight change from this answer - change the order by.

Answer (score 0):

not totally sure what you are trying to accomplish but I think you want something like dense_rank()  here is one I put together  mytable represents your data, t1 does the dense rank check

ok here is the query running after 12:15 and no data is returned.

```
WITH mytable
       AS (SELECT   TO_DATE ('12/3/15 12:00', 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi') AS strt_dt,
                    'Ted' AS person,
                    'Queue_Y' AS grp,
                    123456 AS ticket_num
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   TO_DATE ('12/3/15 12:05', 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi') AS strt_dt,
                    'Bob',
                    NULL,
                    123456
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   TO_DATE ('12/3/15 12:10', 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi') AS strt_dt,
                    'Bob',
                    'Queue_X',
                    123456
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   TO_DATE ('12/3/15 12:15', 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi') AS strt_dt,
                    'Ted',
                    'Queue_Y',
                    123456
             FROM   DUAL),
    t2
       AS (SELECT   mytable.*,
                    DENSE_RANK ()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_num ORDER BY strt_dt DESC)
                       AS test_for_Q
             FROM   mytable)
SELECT   strt_dt, person, grp, ticket_num
  FROM   t2
 WHERE   ticket_num IN (SELECT   ticket_num
                          FROM   t2
                         WHERE   test_for_Q = 1 AND Grp = 'Queue_X')
```

now here is the query running at 12:12 and you get data back.

```
WITH mytable
       AS (SELECT   TO_DATE ('12/3/15 12:00', 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi') AS strt_dt,
                    'Ted' AS person,
                    'Queue_Y' AS grp,
                    123456 AS ticket_num
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   TO_DATE ('12/3/15 12:05', 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi') AS strt_dt,
                    'Bob',
                    NULL,
                    123456
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   TO_DATE ('12/3/15 12:10', 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi') AS strt_dt,
                    'Bob',
                    'Queue_X',
                    123456
             FROM   DUAL
         --  UNION ALL
        --   SELECT   TO_DATE ('12/3/15 12:15', 'mm/dd/yy hh:mi') AS strt_dt,
              --      'Ted',
              --      'Queue_Y',
              --      123456
           --  FROM   DUAL
           ) ,
    t2
       AS (SELECT   mytable.*,
                    DENSE_RANK ()
                       OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_num ORDER BY strt_dt DESC)
                       AS test_for_Q
             FROM   mytable)
SELECT   strt_dt, person, grp, ticket_num
  FROM   t2
 WHERE   ticket_num IN (SELECT   ticket_num
                          FROM   t2
                         WHERE   test_for_Q = 1 AND Grp = 'Queue_X')
```

results

```
STRT_DT,PERSON,GRP,TICKET_NUM
12/3/2015 12:10:00 PM,Bob,Queue_X,123456
12/3/2015 12:05:00 PM,Bob,,123456
12/3/2015 12:00:00 PM,Ted,Queue_Y,123456
```

Comment: Jorge requested more data to work with.  It may help, as I'm only interested in the lastest rows IF marked Queue_X.  I added "Desired Results" to convey what I am talking about.  In the old example, I would only expect the row: `12/3/2015 12:10:00 PM,Bob,Queue_X,123456`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right your query would be:

```
select a.* 
  from ticket_history a
           INNER JOIN ( select PERSON, GROUP, max(STRT_DATE) as maxdt
                          from ticket_history 
                         where group = 'Queue_X'
                         group by PERSON, GROUP ) b
                   ON (    a.person = b.person 
                       and a.group = b.group
                       and a.STRT_DATE = b.maxdt )
 order by a.STRT_DATE desc
```

Please see if it is what you need, otherwise let me know.

Comment: In my larger table, I am still receiving results where Queue_Y is the present owner.

Comment: That´s reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeally odd! Since I am filtering the inner group only with the Queue_X and INNER JOINING the query with this filter. Are you sure that you add the filter in the inner query? `group = 'Queue_X'`. Or I misunderstood your data format

Comment: Does it take into account a change in GROUP?  Say it is in Queue_X then switches to Queue_Y.  I copied you sql exactly and swapped for the actual named values.  The results show GROUP all equal to "Queue_X", however when I check some of the results, there are GROUP changes after the supposed matching.

Comment: @krmarshall87 No, this query doesn't take into account groups change. It would be right to assume that the information to filter would be the TICKET_NUM instead of the group? If this is true, maybe it would give you the right answer.